# requests.exceptions.ConnectionError: HTTPConnectionPool(host='127.0.0.1', port=8000): Max retries exceeded with url: /api/1/

Tags: python, django, api, django-rest-framework

I am trying to communicate between `Django` and `Python` file but I am getting below error :

> requests.exceptions.ConnectionError: HTTPConnectionPool(host='127.0.0.1', port=8000): Max retries exceeded with url: /api/1/ (Caused by NewConnectionError(': Failed to establish a new connection: [WinError 10061] No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it'))

I have created a Python file named `test.py` In a `Django` app and trying to communicate between them. My `Pytho`n file contains below code :

```
import requests
BASE_URL='http://127.0.0.1:8000/'
ENDPOINT='api/'
def get_resource(id):
    resp=requests.get(BASE_URL+ENDPOINT+id+'/')
    print(resp.status_code)
    print(resp.json()) 
id=input("Enter some ID: ")
get_resource(id)
```

`Models.py` contains:-

```
from django.db import models

# Create your models here.
class Employee(models.Model):
    eno=models.IntegerField()
    ename=models.CharField(max_length=70)
    esal=models.FloatField()
    eaddr=models.CharField(max_length=100)
```

`Admin.py` contains:-

```
from django.contrib import admin
from testapp.models import Employee
# Register your models here.
class EmployeeAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display=  ['id','eno','ename','esal','eaddr']

admin.site.register(Employee,EmployeeAdmin)
```

My `Views.py` contains:-

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.views.generic import View
from testapp.models import Employee
import json
from django.http import HttpResponse


class EmployeeDetailCBV(View):
def get(self,request,id,*args,**kwargs):
    emp = Employee.objects.get(id=id)  
    emp_data = {'eno':emp.eno , 'ename':emp.ename , 'esal':emp.esal , 'eaddr':emp.eaddr} 
    json_data=json.dumps(emp_data)
    return HttpResponse(json_data , content_type='application/json')
```

`urls.py` file contains:-

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path
from testapp import views

urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('api/(?P<id>\d+)/$', views.EmployeeDetailCBV.as_view()),
]
```

Getting error like :

> requests.exceptions.ConnectionError: HTTPConnectionPool(host='127.0.0.1', port=8000): Max retries exceeded with url: /api/1/ (Caused by NewConnectionError(': Failed to establish a new connection: [WinError 10061] No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it'))

Please help me. Thank you techies....

Comment: You missed a slash in the URL.

Comment: 127.0.0.8000api   != 127.0.0:80/api/

Answer (score 5):

I got the real reason behind the failure. I had run only py test.py from only 1 terminal to access the python file. At that time the server was not running so commmunication couldn't happen. 
I then opened a separate terminal and ran the Dev server and now my Python file is able to communicate with Django file.
Now its running fine.

Comment: Oops!! Had forgotten to start the `dev-server` first, too. Thanks @Chandan

Answer (score 2):

Try this :

```
import requests

# BASE_URL='http://127.0.0.8000' <<< Url with port malformed
BASE_URL='http://127.0.0.1:8000'
ENDPOINT='api/'
def get_resource():
    # resp=requests.get(BASE_URL+ENDPOINT)  <<< Request url malformed
    resp=requests.get(BASE_URL+"/"+ENDPOINT)
    print(resp.status_code)
    print(resp.json())
get_resource()
```

Comment: Yea I forgot to put / after 8000. Now I've corrected it but again showing the same error

Comment: Thanks for identifying that. My bad. Changed it but again getting same error

Comment: Oh right, the last thing : `http://127.0.0:8000` -> `http://127.0.0.1:8000`. So obvious, that I couldn't see it !

Comment: It seems I'm drunk and trying to code. Sorry for missing that. Changed it but I don't know why it's throwing same error again and again

Comment: What happens when you go to `http://127.0.0.1:8000/api` from your browser ?

Comment: Yea now I'm able to get the data I had created in admin page. But when I'm trying to retrieve same information through Python file i.e, test.py I'm still getting requests.exceptions.ConnectionError: HTTPConnectionPool(host='127.0.0.1', port=8000): Max retries exceeded with url: /api/1/ (Caused by NewConnectionError('<urllib3.connection.HTTPConnection object at 0x04219250>: Failed to establish a new connection: [WinError 10061] No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it'))

Answer (score 2):

To launch your code locally, use your fixed IPv4 address.

For Windows users: open a command prompt (cmd) and run the `ipconfig` command, retrieve the `IP@` which is at `IPv4 address. . . . . . . . . . . . . .`: it is generally of type `192.168.x.x`

IPv4 address in command prompt

then go to your `settings.py` and add: `ALLOWED_HOSTS = ['*']`

Answer (score 0):

Faced similar problem, changing port number solved the issue.

Comment: If you are not planning to give an answer, just go to "add a comment"

Answer (score 0):

please check your port once
in my case I had port issue I have used port 8525, instead of browsing 8525 I have browsed with 8000

Answer (score 0):

You just need to open separate terminal and run your python code and

### make sure your server is running at that time

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).